# Aristarchus' Inequality - algebraic proof

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

While looking for trigonometric inequalities, I stumbled upon Aristarchus' inequality, which states that for $0<\alpha<\beta<\pi/2$

> $$\frac{\sin(\beta)}{\sin(\alpha)}<\frac{\beta}{\alpha}<\frac{\tan(\beta)}{\tan(\alpha)}.$$

In this post
([Proof of Aristarchus' Inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536253/proof-of-aristarchus-inequality)) user141614 shows a completely algebraic proof of the first inequality using only $\sin(\alpha)<\alpha<\tan(\alpha)$.

I tried for a long time to reproduce a similar proof for $\tan$ by trying to prove the equivalent inequality
$$\frac{\tan(\beta)-\tan(\alpha)}{\beta-\alpha}>\frac{\tan(\alpha)}{\alpha},$$
by using user141614's same idea, combined with trigonometric identities for the sum and product, but without success.

Does someone have hint on how to approach the problem? I really want an algebraic proof (which can potentially rely on easy-to-prove inequalities as the one above), no calculus.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to find an easy proof:

For $0<\alpha<\beta<\pi/2$ we have
$1>\cos(\alpha)>\cos(\beta)>0$
and thus (the orange chain was known)
$$0<\sin(\alpha)\cos(\alpha)<\color{orange} {\sin(\alpha)<\alpha<\tan(\alpha)}=\frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\cos(\alpha)}<\color{red}{\frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\cos(\beta)}}.$$
Consequently, using that $0<\beta-\alpha<\beta$ in the previous equation (replacing $\alpha$ by $\beta-\alpha$) we obtain:
$$\color{orange}{\beta-\alpha}<\color{red}{\frac{\sin(\beta-\alpha)}{\cos(\beta)}}=\tan(\beta)\cos(\alpha)-\sin(\alpha).$$
We conclude that
\begin{align*}
\frac{\beta}{\alpha}&=\frac{\beta-\alpha}{\alpha}+1\\ &
<\frac{\tan(\beta)\cos(\alpha)-\sin(\alpha)}{\sin(\alpha)}+1\\
& = \frac{\tan(\beta)}{\tan(\alpha)}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Oh! this is colorful answer ^^

Comment: Thank you @BlackMild